# jQuery Hover Problem

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get an element on my page to disappear and reappear when a user clicks on another element. My code looks like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.affordable').hover(function () {
        $('#reason-a').toggle();
    });
</script>

<span class="affordable">Affordable</span>
<span class="turnaround">Fast Turnaround</span>
<span class="communication">Communication</span>

<div id="reason-a">Affordable information</div>
```

I want the user to be able to hover on the affordable class, and then the affordable information is shown. And then when the user hovers off the word, the information should disappear.

Many thanks

Comment: @dele  jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/4xruD/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the way the script is actually setup?  You'll want to put the script inside an onload handler:

```
$(function(){
  // Register your hover events here
});
```

The reason being is the element your binding your function too doesn't exist yet and the selector is returning an empty array (so you're not really binding anything).

The toggle method alternates visibility with no parameters, and the hover method acts as mouseenter and mouseleave with a single delegate passed in, so I think the suggestions to switch to separate functions for hide and show are unnecessary.

Comment: I also agree with the below answer that you'll want to toggle/hide reason-a in your load script so it doesn't display initially (or do this with CSS).

Answer (score 1):

you should like this

add css display none for #reason-a so it won't show on load

```
#reason-a{ 
display:none
}
```

working demo

**http://jsfiddle.net/4xruD/**

wrap the code over document.ready also

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".affordable").hover(
      function () {
        $("#reason-a").show(); // this is mouse over
      }, 
      function () {
        $("#reason-a").hide(); // this is mouseout
      }
    );


});
```

Comment: +1 for the slick solution. Also I tweaked your code to use the OPs very correct use of .toggle().  The minor change can be found here. http://jsfiddle.net/4xruD/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reason-a').hide();
    $('.affordable').hover(
    function () {
       $('#reason-a').show();
    },
    function () {
       $('#reason-a').hide();
    });
});
```